# Shiro - "No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code..." exception in Grails app

Tags: grails, shiro

I'm in the process of converting a rather large Grails 2 application to Grails 4. It uses the Shiro plugin, which I have upgraded to version 4.3 (`compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-shiro:4.3"`). In one large GSP (which has always worked OK), the Shiro taglib is now causing the following error:

`Error executing tag <shiro:isLoggedIn>: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.`

The SecurityManager is initialized OK in Bootstrap.groovy, and in another simple test page, shiro:isLoggedIn works fine. So my question is why might the SecurityManager not be available in this use of the taglib? What should I be looking out for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Grails person, but one common reason folks see this problem is that the `ShiroFilter` did not process the request (or the filter is not configured early enough in the chain).

What happens is the `ShiroFilter` creates a `Subject` (the user) and associates it and the `SecurityManager` with the request thread. Other API (like the tag lib) would use that `Subject` and/or `SecurityManager`.

Check your servlet filters, maybe compare them with the old version with the new version and see what has changed.

Comment: I'm having extraordinary difficulty in getting to the bottom of this one. There are no differences between old and new in the filter I am using, although the plugin code has changed. Could I perhaps do something like 
`if(!ThreadContext.getSecurityManager()) {
                    
                    ThreadContext.bind(shiroSecurityManager)//injected
               
 }`
to ensure the security manager is present when needed?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is related to the change in the Grails plugin.  I'm still guessing the root cause of the problem is related to the page getting processed before the filter (or equivalent for Grails) is applied.  Was there anything in the change log for the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

G'day John, I look after the grails shiro plugin. That error occurs in the taglib because for some reason I'm trying to track down, the ThreadContext doesn't appear to be available. That means the SecurityUtils goes looking for a static security Manager which isn't normally set in web applications.

So basically it's a bug, and hopefully I'll fix it shortly (help welcome).